# Java on Win server, bat run packages

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file

To begin with, I dont know much Java, but we have some old Java applications on my firm that collects information that runs every night, however recently it stopped working. There is a bat file that, from what I understand, runs all the required packages, however, when I run it, it returns "Could not find or load main class -insert whatever class I put second - "

Code from the .bat file:

```
java -cp com.spprod.mywysiwyg.NY.jar; mysql-connector-java-3.1.10-bin.jar; com.spprod.mywysiwyg.CalculateDailyStats;
```

The first one is the whole package, and the second one is the connector, they are both in the same folder, but in the cmd I get the error that it cant find mysql. If I switch order with 2nd and 3rd it says that I cant find "CalculateDailyStats" instead. Is there something wrong with this line of code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the error text as well. Without looking at it it would be difficult to find exact root cause

Comment: The command line you have posted is drivel. If it worked before, someone has broken it. Revert to a backup, and don't let people fiddle with things they don't understand.

Comment: Hi @EJP, yes I totally agree. However, as is now, im the only developer present, and I'm just a junior straight outta school. I did not touch the code so therefore I was very confused when all of a sudden it did not work anymore. However, the answer from Plirkee seem to have done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-cp` switch specifies the `classpath` in `java` (path where to look for the files). The `jars` after `-cp` are separated with semicolon.

Now, I suppose, that you are trying to run `com.spprod.mywysiwyg.CalculateDailyStats` `class`. So, maybe the last semicolons are confusing e.g. try the following:

```
java -cp com.spprod.mywysiwyg.NY.jar;mysql-connector-java-3.1.10-bin.jar com.spprod.mywysiwyg.CalculateDailyStats
```

Comment: Hi @Plirkee, thank you! It seems to have solved my problem, thank you alot!